# A combination of keys turned off my computer. What those keys could have been?

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts

On *Debian 10*, in a *GNOME* session,

Yesterday, I hit a combination of keys instead of the one I had in mind, not really aware of what I was doing.

The effect was immediate : the *Eclipse* IDE I was on saved it's workspace and my computer turned off.

What this keys combination I have hit could have been ?

Comment: Are you on a laptop? Is it possible you just accidentally hit the power button? I've done that before on my Dell latitude.

Comment: @BrandonZappy No. It's a classical computer tower.

Comment: The "power" button (usually left of numlock) is doing a (clean) poweroff by default. Except that it's not always labeled as "Power" ;-) (I've seen keyboards where the Stop Prev/NextTrack and Sleep/Wake/Power are swapped)

Comment: I have the same (and perfect) Key Ttronic keyboard for twenty-five years : here it's model : it has no power button on it : https://i.imgur.com/FFLxzZZ.jpg

Comment: You *possibly* hit Alt + SysReq (Print Screen) + B. That will reboot your computer instantly. It's usually used as REISUB (busier backwards is an easy way to remember it) to reboot a frozen Linux.

Comment: @KGIII A good combination to learn, thanks ! But my computer was turned off, not rebooted. I had to power-on it to start it again.

Comment: Your keyboard may not have a power button, but your system may think differently. If you're on X11, run `xkbcomp $DISPLAY -` and look for anything interesting  `| grep -C3 -i pow`

Comment: @user414777 : the command show nothing. I have a normal PC with a classical screen display under GNOME. I don't think I use X11. (I don't really know what it is).